# Automatic Input to a dialogue box in Windows

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

I have a Virtual Smart Card installed on my PC. Whenever I have to connect to various applications, I am prompted to input the pin. Is there anyway to automate this process?

I tried using AutoHotKey for this, but couldn't write a solution for this.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried? And give more Info about the window and the input field, this you can get with the WinSpy that come with the autohotkey installer....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#Persistent
Return

F7::
SendInput, EnterYourPinHere
Return
```

When you press F7, it will type out what ever you have after the `Send` command.